# How to append text to TextBlock in loop immediatelly?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new WPF.

I'm trying to print some information in my WPF application. I wrote simple method that appends text to `TextBlock` called `tbLog` and I want to use it like console output.

```
private void WriteLn(string text)
{
    tbLog.Text += text + Environment.NewLine; // tbLog is a TextBlock
}
```

Now I'm trying to use it in a loop.

```
foreach (var day in listOfDays)
{
    Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
    watch.Start();
    double[] aData = GetDayData(data, day); // I'm using EF6 DbContext here
    alData.Add(aData); 
    WriteLn("Processing " + day.Date.Date + " took " + watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "s");
}
```

**Effect of `WriteLn()` is not visible immediatelly (after each loop run). All printed data shows up after whole loop ends.
How can I fix that?**

My `GetDayData()` method used in a loop uses Entity Framework 6 `DbContext`.

Comment: You have to run your loop in a separate background thread. In WriteLn, use Dispatcher.Invoke. If that is not clear enough, I can write an example code.

Comment: Why don't you switch to something mainstream for logging like Log4Net

Comment: @Evk Thanks, I got this. I'll write an answer with working code.

Comment: @Ggalla1779 I'm not using log4net because: 1) I didn't knew it much. 2) I guess it is too big and complicated for my needs. Simple WriteLn() method is enough for me right now.

Answer (score 4):

So, thanks to [Evk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5311735/evk) I fixed my code like this:

'WriteLn' part:

```
private void WriteLn(string text)
{
    tbLog.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        tbLog.Text += text + Environment.NewLine;
    }));
}
```

Loop part:

```
Thread t = new Thread(() => 
        {
            foreach (var day in listOfDays)
            {
                Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();
                double[] aData = GetDayData(data, day);
                alData.Add(aData);
                WriteLn("Processing " + day.Date.Date + " took " + watch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + "s");

                id++;
            }
        });

t.Start();
```